# Parent / tree referential integrity check for European Waste Catalogue codes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to create a database, part of which involves storing the European Waste Catalogue (EWC) code.

An EWC code is a hierarchical 2, 4, or 6 digit code, where the first 2 characters represent chapters, the next 2 represent sub-chapters, and the final 2 represent waste descriptions.

For example:
`02` Wastes from Agriculture, Horticulture, Aquaculture, Forestry, Hunting and Fishing, Food Preparation and Processing
`0202` wastes from the preparation and processing of meat. Fish and other foods of animal origin
`020203` materials unsuitable for consumption or processing

The entire tree needs to be stored, so I wanted to make sure the parent exists when creating the child record.

However... I'm a little stumped on how to approach this. A foreign key that doesn't directly reference a column (That is: attempts to call a function first) triggers a syntax error:

```
...
foreign key substring(ewc_code, 1, length(ewc_code) - 2) references cdsw_data.ewc_codes (ewc_code) match simple on update restrict on delete cascade
...
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "substring"
LINE 5:  foreign key substring(ewc_code, 1, length(ewc_code) - 2) re...
```

Could anyone direct me toward a proper solution for this please?

Table structure:

```sql
create table cdsw_data.ewc_codes (
    ewc_code varchar(6) primary key,
    ewc_descrition text,
    constraint valid_ewc check(ewc_code ~ '^(\d\d){1,3}$')
);
```

Comment: That's a "smart" business field that shouldn't be used as a key. Extract the relevant information to other fields and use *those* for constraints, FKs to lookup tables etc. This case is slightly complicated because each field has an implicit `All` entry. If you decide to use lookup tables you'd have to add a `0, All` entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could think of 3 approaches:

- use 3 different tables, one with a two-digit column, one with two two-digit columns, and one with three two-digit columns. Use those as composite primary keys. Declare foreign-key references to the columns of the parent table. Have a (possibly overloaded) function to compute the full key as a single string.
- do all the integrity checks with a trigger function
- use a helper column that can be used as the foreign key and is asserted to have the expected value:

  ```
  create table cdsw_data.ewc_codes (
      ewc_code varchar(6) primary key,
      ewc_parentcode varchar(4) references cdsw_data.ewc_codes,
      ewc_description text,
      constraint valid_ewc check(ewc_code ~ '^(\d\d){1,3}$'),
      constraint parent check(ewc_parentcode is not distinct from 
                              null_if(left(ewc_code, -2), ''))
  );
  ```